# How to capture SessionNotFoundException thrown by webdriver because of appium session timeout

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I need to handle the following exception thrown by my suite when running the test on Chrome browser on Android real device using Appium 1.4.16.1. I believe the exception is thrown because of a timeout (set to 10s) on Appium, after which the session is deleted. However, once the exception is thrown by Selenium Webdriver (at line `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(UILoc)))`), it is not caught using catch block and any further execution is hanged.

Note that same test case when executed on desktop chrome browser is able to catch the exception.

Please let me know if there is a way to catch this, as I need to do further handling. Note that I can avoid the situation by increasing timeout of Appium session. However, I still want to handle the max limit.

**Appium Timeout Logs**

```
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/url {"url":"http://test.com"}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/url] to [POST hubsession] with body: {"url":"http://test.com"}
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 10 secs, shutting down...
> info: Shutting down appium session
> info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'stopping'
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE hubsession] with no body
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b","status":0,"value":null}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Replacing sessionId 5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b with 5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/url 200 110858.244 ms - 72 
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//div[@id='form-1010']"}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/element] to [POST hubsession] with body: {"using":"xpath","value":"//div[@id='form-1010']"}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b\",\"status\":0,\"value\":null}"
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"","status":6,"value":{"message":"no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)"}}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b/element 200 743.048 ms - 189 
> info: Chromedriver: Changed state to 'stopped'
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"OK, shutting down","status":0}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
```

**Webdriver Exception Logs**

```
Aug 17, 2016 12:49:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //div[@id='form-1010'])
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 753 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'Pune832', ip: '10.10.148.44', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129)}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=true, version=52.0.2743.98, platform=ANDROID, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5ff4eaccea1df145b80f6df4af4c3d7b
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@id='form-1010']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:899)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:897)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find element using the given xpath.  *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@id='form-1010']}

Since you are using ID as locator so I would suggest to use the below code -

```
driver.findElements(By.id("form-1010"));
```

I use the below code to check if element is present or not. If element is not present, it will capture error logs.

```
protected boolean isElementPresent(By by) throws IOException {
    boolean isElement = false;
    try
    {
        if (driver.findElement(by) != null)
        {
            isElement = true;
            return isElement;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Element not found");
        isElement = false;
        return isElement;
    }
    return isElement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however what i am looking for is a way to catch this exception which is caused by SessionNotFoundException in above case (when appium deletes the session). Using try/catch block for this does not captures.

Comment: Define driver as static driver and check if its null. when the driver is null it means appium session is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing timeout 60 seconds when launching the appium server. Timeout can be passed as argument to the appium server.

`--command-timeout  60`

The default command timeout for the server to use for all sessions. Will still be overridden by newCommandTimeout cap`